# How to upload an image file in multipart to the server in react-native?

Tags: android, react-native

I am developing an app in `react-native`.
I am choosing an image from the image picker in the Android device and want to upload this file in multipart to the server in a `POST` request.

Answer (score -1):

You should create a form data and push the files that you want to send to your api.

```
                       const sendableFormData = new FormData();

                        photos.map((element: any, index: number) => {
                            const imageUrl: any = {
                                uri: element.uri,
                                type: element.mime,
                                name: `imageFilename-${index}`,
                            };
                       sendableFormData.append('imageUrls', imageUrl, `imageFilename-${index}`);

axios(
            {
                method: 'post',
                url: `url`,
                data: sendableFormData,
                headers: { 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' },
            },
        );
```